# using 2 desktops with 2 gpus

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, multiple-desktops

I'm running CUDA programs on my NVIDIA card (having it at 100% usage), and I want to be able to use my iGPU meanwhile to surf the net or program meanwhile.

I also want to be able to play games on my NVIDIA when not running my programs on it without the need to reboot my computer.

I've seen people who do GPU passthrough, connect their monitor to both the iGPU and the NVIDIA card and so they can run 2 desktops.

This seems a bit much considering I don't want a different OS, I just want my Ubuntu to show 2 desktops (no interactions between the desktops needed, i.e. no need to pass windows between them) - do I have to run a virtual Ubuntu on top of my Ubuntu with GPU passthrough, or is there a better way to achieve that?

I guess I'd also have to map my keyboard and mouse to different USB ports to switch between desktops...

Answer (score 1):

So, this is not exactly what I was asking for, but I found a solution that does what I want.

I wanted something that would let me use my computer with my iGPU while the NVIDIA GPU was busy with computations, and easily switch back to it to play games when it's not being used for computations.

The solution is using NVIDIA Prime.

I haven't yet done it myself, but I did find [instructions](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/991849/-solved-run-cuda-on-dedicated-nvidia-gpu-while-connecting-monitors-to-intel-hd-graphics-is-this-possible-/):

> In summary, in order to make this to work, you need to
>
> 1. make sure you have enabled onboard graphics in the BIOS settings (or set it as primary)
> 2. install both xorg intel driver and nvidia/cuda drivers
> 3. start nvidia-settings, and go to the PRIME settings page, set Intel (Power Saving Mode) as default
> 4. modify your .bashrc and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to at least contain /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/lib/nvidia-XXX where XXX in my case is 375.
> 5. logout to restart X or reboot
> 6. run ldd $( which glxinfo ) to make sure your GL libraries point to mesa, or run glmark2 to confirm GL status
> 7. (update) if the libGL printed from step 5 points to nvidia's driver folder, you need to remove/rename the
>      libGL.so*/libGLX.so*/libGLdispatch.so* under nvidia driver folder so
>      that your OS can pick up the mesa libGL library.
> 8. run nvidia-smi to list your dedicated NVIDIA GPU, and run your CUDA program, you should not see any errors.